# Efficiency of a cast vs a shift

Tags: programming, c++, compile

I'm using a supplied library which uses a number of (non-sequential) outputs to latch a multiplexer. The code looks (in part) like this:

```
 digitalWrite(_S0, (chan & 1));    
 digitalWrite(_S1, (chan & 3)>>1); 
 digitalWrite(_S2, (chan & 7)>>2); 
 digitalWrite(_S3, (chan & 15)>>3);
```

Those masks seem a little odd, but it would work. More natural to me would be:

```
 digitalWrite(_S0, (chan & 1));    
 digitalWrite(_S1, (chan & 2)>>1); 
 digitalWrite(_S2, (chan & 4)>>2); 
 digitalWrite(_S3, (chan & 8)>>3);
```

But overall, would it be more efficient to do this?

```
 digitalWrite(_S0,       (chan & 1));    
 digitalWrite(_S1, (bool)(chan & 2)); 
 digitalWrite(_S2, (bool)(chan & 4)); 
 digitalWrite(_S3, (bool)(chan & 8));
```

...or is shifting already pretty efficient?

I've actually re-written the code to build a mask and use PORTx to latch it all at once, so this is really an academic question, but I'm still curious.

Comment: The `digitalWrite` calls are the slowest parts in here. It takes about 50 (or more) instruction cycles (if I remember it correctly), so few more or less cycles won't make so big difference.

Comment: @KIIV - Sure, that's why I replaced all this with an array of bitmasks and a single PORTx access. It's probably 20x faster. I was just curious about efficiency in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried compiling your three snippets with avr-gcc 4.9.2 at the `-Os`
optimization level (standard with Arduino) but *without* `-flto`. The
results were:

- The first snippet generated inefficient code: the ands and shifts were
  translated in assembly quite literally, the shifts were done on
  16 bits even though `chan` was declared `uint8_t`, and the last
  shift was even implemented as a loop roughly equivalent to
  `uint16_t tmp1 = chan & 15; uint8_t tmp2 = 3; while (--tmp2) tmp1 <<= 1;`
- The second and third snippets were translated identically and
  efficiently, using the `bst` (bit store) and `bld` (bit load)
  instructions to copy the relevant bit of `chan` into the second
  argument of the `digitalWrite()` call.

Personally I would just write

```
digitalWrite(_S0, chan & 1);    
digitalWrite(_S1, chan & 2); 
digitalWrite(_S2, chan & 4); 
digitalWrite(_S3, chan & 8);
```

as `digitalWrite()` expects an integer as its second argument, and it
interprets it just like the `(bool)` cast does. If you want to be sure
to always call `digitalWrite()` with either 0 (`LOW`) or 1 (`HIGH`),
then use either your second of third form. The first form seems formally
equivalent to the second, but since it is *not* an usual C idiom, the
compiler could not catch the optimization opportunity.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. I can see how the `(bool)` cast would be redundant in this case. Also very interesting that the compiler knows 'idioms'.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the assembly code the compiler produces, you can see it compiles to the exact same thing - when using a constant.:

```
void setup() {
  ....
  digitalWrite(_S1, (chan & 2)>>1); 
 282:   84 e0           ldi r24, 0x04   ; 4
 284:   0e 94 6b 00     call    0xd6    ; 0xd6 <digitalWrite.constprop.0>
 ....
  digitalWrite(_S1, (bool)(chan & 2)); 
 29a:   84 e0           ldi r24, 0x04   ; 4
 29c:   0e 94 6b 00     call    0xd6    ; 0xd6 <digitalWrite.constprop.0>
```

However, using a variable produces different results:

```
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(_S0, (chan & 1));    
 2a2:   c0 91 00 01     lds r28, 0x0100 ; 0x800100 <__data_start>
 2a6:   d0 91 01 01     lds r29, 0x0101 ; 0x800101 <__data_start+0x1>
 2aa:   6c 2f           mov r22, r28
 2ac:   61 70           andi    r22, 0x01   ; 1
 2ae:   83 e0           ldi r24, 0x03   ; 3
 2b0:   0e 94 76 00     call    0xec    ; 0xec <digitalWrite>
  digitalWrite(_S1, (chan & 2)>>1); 
 2b4:   6c 2f           mov r22, r28
 2b6:   66 95           lsr r22
 2b8:   61 70           andi    r22, 0x01   ; 1
 2ba:   84 e0           ldi r24, 0x04   ; 4
 2bc:   0e 94 76 00     call    0xec    ; 0xec <digitalWrite>
  digitalWrite(_S2, (chan & 4)>>2); 
 2c0:   c2 fb           bst r28, 2
 2c2:   66 27           eor r22, r22
 2c4:   60 f9           bld r22, 0
 2c6:   85 e0           ldi r24, 0x05   ; 5
 2c8:   0e 94 76 00     call    0xec    ; 0xec <digitalWrite>
  digitalWrite(_S3, (chan & 8)>>3); 
 2cc:   c3 fb           bst r28, 3
 2ce:   66 27           eor r22, r22
 2d0:   60 f9           bld r22, 0
 2d2:   86 e0           ldi r24, 0x06   ; 6
 2d4:   0e 94 76 00     call    0xec    ; 0xec <digitalWrite>

 ....

  digitalWrite(_S0,       (chan & 1));    
 2a2:   c0 91 00 01     lds r28, 0x0100 ; 0x800100 <__data_start>
 2a6:   d0 91 01 01     lds r29, 0x0101 ; 0x800101 <__data_start+0x1>
 2aa:   6c 2f           mov r22, r28
 2ac:   61 70           andi    r22, 0x01   ; 1
 2ae:   83 e0           ldi r24, 0x03   ; 3
 2b0:   0e 94 76 00     call    0xec    ; 0xec <digitalWrite>
  digitalWrite(_S1, (bool)(chan & 2)); 
 2b4:   be 01           movw    r22, r28
 2b6:   76 95           lsr r23
 2b8:   67 95           ror r22
 2ba:   61 70           andi    r22, 0x01   ; 1
 2bc:   84 e0           ldi r24, 0x04   ; 4
 2be:   0e 94 76 00     call    0xec    ; 0xec <digitalWrite>
  digitalWrite(_S2, (bool)(chan & 4)); 
 2c2:   be 01           movw    r22, r28
 2c4:   76 95           lsr r23
 2c6:   67 95           ror r22
 2c8:   76 95           lsr r23
 2ca:   67 95           ror r22
 2cc:   61 70           andi    r22, 0x01   ; 1
 2ce:   85 e0           ldi r24, 0x05   ; 5
 2d0:   0e 94 76 00     call    0xec    ; 0xec <digitalWrite>
  digitalWrite(_S3, (bool)(chan & 8)); 
 2d4:   be 01           movw    r22, r28
 2d6:   23 e0           ldi r18, 0x03   ; 3
 2d8:   76 95           lsr r23
 2da:   67 95           ror r22
 2dc:   2a 95           dec r18
 2de:   e1 f7           brne    .-8         ; 0x2d8 <main+0xc0>
 2e0:   61 70           andi    r22, 0x01   ; 1
 2e2:   86 e0           ldi r24, 0x06   ; 6
 2e4:   0e 94 76 00     call    0xec    ; 0xec <digitalWrite>
```

Comment: Your test is not really significant. The compiler noticed that you were always calling `digitalWrite()` with 0 (i.e. `LOW`) as its second argument. It then generated a specialized variant of `digitalWrite()` that sets an output to `LOW` and it translated your code into something like `digitalWriteLow(3); digitalWriteLow(4); digitalWriteLow(5); digitalWriteLow(6);`. In order for the test to be significant, you should make sure `chan` is not a compile-time constant. Alternatively, compile _without_ the `-flto` flag to force the compiler into creating a non-specialized translation of your code.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that `chan` is a passed-in variable. Using a constant `chan` would make this trivial, as you say.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Fair assessment. I did make it a `const`. Will update...

Comment: Your updated test is flawed again. The compiler computed `chan & 2` while translating `(chan & 2)>>1`, and it stored this intermediate result in the `r11:r10` register pair. Then, when translating `(bool)(chan & 2)`, it used the fact that `chan & 2` was already in a the register file, which made that translation shorter.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Thanks for your input. The answer turned out to be more complex than I initially assumed.